How do I replicate [FromBody] Web API functionality with Minimal APIs?
In ASP.NET Core Web API, I may have an endpoint as follows:
[HttpPost("doSomething")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] SomeObject request)
{
    // ...
}

With an object like this:
public class SomeObject
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}

When calling the above endpoint, I must supply Subject, Body, and Priority in the post request, or else I will encounter an exception. This is a good thing, as I know the client has provided these values (whether or not they're default values, null or whitespace is immaterial - I just need to make sure the client has supplied them, and Web API checks this for me).
Now with Minimal APIs, I'm attempting to replicate the above behaviour with this code:
app.MapPost("/doSomething", async ([FromBody] SomeObject request) =>
{
    // ...
});

The problem? While I can access the values of request, there is no guarantee the client has supplied all the values for the object. No exception is thrown if they haven't. I must now do manual checking for every field.
I'm wondering if there's a simple solution either

Built directly into Minimal APIs that ensure the client supplies all required fields, or
Writing some generic middleware that will ensure the client has supplied all the required fields of the [FromBody] type (I'm guessing via reflection)?

Maybe something like this:
app.MapPost<T>("/doSomething", async ([FromBody] T request) =>
{
    // ...
});

Where I can just put the specific type for that endpoint in place of T (not saying it's how it will be done, but just an example of a type of generic solution I'm after).
So in essence my question is: How do I replicate the [FromBody] behaviour from Web API in Minimal APIs, particularly related to exception throwing if the client calling the endpoint doesn't supply all the required fields for the object?

You can use endpoint filters to add validators to the calls https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0 or use FluentValidation to do it directly

@SamiKuhmonen Thanks, is it possible for a code sample? It looks like an awful lot of boilerplate there, and I need to make a new type per object? Can I use a generic so I don't need to rewrite things? I'm after a simple solution like MVC provides. Something like .AddEndpointFilter() would be perfect, where Object is simply the [FromBody] Object. but it doesn't seem that simple per the link.

You can use the Fluent Validation library to validate your incoming requests.
For example:
public record SomeObject
{
    public string Subject { get; init; }

    public string Body { get; init; }
}

public class SomeObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<SomeObject>
{
    private const int MaxSubjectLength = 250;

    private const int MaxBodyLength = 3000;

    public SomeObjectValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(_ => _.Subject)
            .NotEmpty()
            .MaximumLength(MaxSubjectLength)
            .WithMessage($"The subject must be no longer than {MaxSubjectLength} characters");

        RuleFor(_ => _.Body)
            .NotEmpty()
            .MaximumLength(MaxBodyLength)
            .WithMessage($"Body cannot exceed {MaxBodyLength} characters");
    }
}

app.MapPost("/dosomething", async ([FromBody] SomeObject request, IValidator<SomeObject> validator) =>
{
    var validationResult = await validator.ValidateAsync(request);

    if (!validationResult.IsValid)
    {
        return Results.ValidationProblem(validationResult.ToDictionary());
    }

    // continue with rest of your logic
});

To hook it together, you need to register your validation with the IoC container.
builder
    .Services
    .AddScoped<IValidator<SomeObject>, SomeObjectValidator>();

